# Install Windows 10 on OSX Parallels - Setup Media Driver Missing

Tags: windows, macos, parallels

I got an error whilst installing Windows 10 from .iso file as virtual machine via Parallels 9 on OSX 10.10 which read something like: `Media driver missing`. It leaves you in a loop which requires you to add the drivers. But you cannot install any cause there are no suggestions.

Now the main issue seemed that the iso wasn't on a bootable device which is what most sources say you need to do. Obviously that seemed like an unneeded step and i got the installation going. Mostly because you were already inside the installation that had been booted in the first place.

Software i use:
OSX 10.10 (latest)
Parallels 9 (latest updates, i know Parallels 10 is out)
Windows 10 iso from http://preview.windows.com
VM setup with iso from external HD (NTFS) and locally stored.

So what to do?

(see my answer below)

Comment: Why the -1? It has all the info, doesn't it?

Comment: The solution works perfectly. Already fixed that silly -1.

Answer (score 31):

What you can do is shut down your virtual machine (close out the installation first to make sure). Go to the settings of the parallels by clicking:

-> Menubar: `Virtual Machine`

-> `Configure`

-> `Hardware tab`

-> `CD/DVD 1` (where your image is inserted)

-> `Location` dropdown

-> Select `IDE 0:1` (instead of `SATA 0:1`)

-> Restart VM

Done!

Installation will continue normally and you can start trying Windows 10 from Parallels 9 on your Mac.

I'm not sure if this works for Parallels 10 (i think so) and i'm also not sure if this will work for other (older) Windows installations. But to remove the steps required for making a bootable disk is good enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell to parallels to install it as windows xp and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs, also, when you have a MacBook Pro (10,2 or similar) without a DVD drive, while installing Windows 10 via USB.

So, during the Parallels 10 or 11 Guest setup, choose to configure using an ISO instead.